VFD display AC filament drive
I have a Futaba 11-ST-26ZA I bought at a bargain sale, with attached datasheet. I'm currently in the process of building a driver for this VFD, but I'm a little confused about how to drive the filament of this VFD. I have already read this question, in which they use a FET bridge to drive the AC filament.
However, I am using the output of a NE556 to drive the input of a summing amplifier (see simulation below) to produce a ~3-4 VAC signal.

Can I just apply the 4 VAC output to the +ve pin of the VFD and the -ve pin to ground? Pinout of the 11-ST-26ZA VFD is below, taken from the datasheet. The opamp is a LM324, with a 2N3904 and 2N3906 as output.

UPDATE: I have tested hacktastical's suggestion of driving the display filament with DC, however, this results in the end digits being quite dim when compared to the first few digits.

Make sure -ve is the lower voltage. Try swapping the filament connections.

Swapped the +- ve terminals, the brightness gradient is very visible now. The first few digits are considerably dimmer than the last few now.

This VFD has a filament requires a DC drive, not AC, set to a specific voltage. How do I know this? The lead labels are (-ve) and (+ve), and - wait for it - the filament voltage is given as 4.5V DC.
This matters: to ensure even brightness, the filament is tilted to compensate for the DC voltage gradient that's developed across it when it's lit up.
Does this make things a bit easier? Indeed, it does: your AC driver is completely unnecessary. And since the drive is +4.5V, you can just use +5V with just a little bit of work.
Whatever you do, you first need to ensure that the most negative grid / anode voltage is below the filament (cathode) -ve voltage.
Let's say you use positive grid/anode voltage drive (0/+12V.) You could use +5V to power the filament, with a small addition: a series diode.
As follows:

+ve - connect to +5V
-ve - connect to diode anode
diode cathode - connect to GND

This will give a 4.5V DC drive to the filament, lifted about 500mV above GND. That lift is helpful to ensure grid pinch-off.
Your voltages should be:

Grid/Seg 'on': +12V
+ve: +5V
-ve: +500mV
Grid/Seg 'off': GND

Then you only need to worry about level-shifting your GPIOs to 12V. The 74LS07 with pull-ups would be ok for this.
More about driving VFDs here: https://www.noritake-elec.com/technology/general-technical-information/vfd-operation
MORE:
This AC drive circuit would probably work (simulate it here).

This accepts a PWM signal from your micro which you can use to control filament current.
This circuit does something special: during PWM 'off' time it holds the filament at the bias setting, ensuring consistent cathode-to-anode voltage.
If you don't need PWM control and prefer just to supply a clock, bypass the tristate buffers after the flip-flop. The bias input will still set the AC midpoint.
The output transistors can be 2N3904/2N3906 or similar.

Just a note of clarification, if Ek is the filament voltage(which I glossed over, oops), what does Ei refer to? I initially thought the filament needed AC due to the other question I mentioned, but it seems this is not the case.

I honestly don’t know what EI means. As far as AC drive, yes the other question got it wrong too.

Hmm. I just tested the VFD with a DC driven filament(it works), but the end digits are quite dim.

Maybe you have a variant of this display that requires AC drive (and you have the wrong data sheet?) Look closely at the filament stand-offs to see if they are equal or unequal. If they're equal, it'll need AC.
